# Не могу записать потомка дальше второго узла бинарного дерева

Tags: c++, алгоритм, бинарное-дерево

Думаю проблема в функции `search_and_second_insert`.

Вопрос: в чём именно может заключаться ошибка?

```
using std::wcin;
using std::wcout;
using std::endl;
using std::locale;

struct Books
{
    wchar_t number_UDK[10];
    wchar_t FIO_autors[20];
    wchar_t name_of_the_book[20];
    wint_t year_izd;
    wchar_t Kolvo[50];
};

struct Node
{
    Books book;
    Node* left, *right, *chaild;
};

Node* Input(Node* tree, int n)
{
    tree = new Node;
    wcout << L"Введите данные книги." << endl;
    wcout << L"ФИО Автора: ";
    wcin >> tree->book.FIO_autors;
    wcout << endl;
    wcout << L"Номер УДК: ";
    wcin >> tree->book.number_UDK;
    wcout << endl;
    wcout << L"Название книги: ";
    wcin >> tree->book.name_of_the_book;
    wcout << endl;
    wcout << L"Количество экземпляров: ";
    wcin >> tree->book.Kolvo;
    wcout << endl;
    wcout << L"Год издания: ";
    wcin >> tree->book.year_izd;
    wcin.get();
    wcout << endl;

    if (n == 0)
        tree->chaild = tree;

    tree->left = tree->right = NULL;
    return tree;
}

Node* search_and_second_insert(Node* tree)
{
    Node* parent = tree;
    bool found = false;

    while (parent && !found)
    {
        if ((tree->chaild->book.year_izd ==
                parent->book.year_izd)/* && (tree->chaild == parent)*/)
            ** не видит следующий после второго узла, т.е конечный tree->chaild**
            found = true;
        else if (tree->chaild->book.year_izd < parent->book.year_izd)
            parent = parent->left;
        else parent = parent->right;
    }

    if (found)
        return parent;
}

Node* Second_Insert(Node* p, int n)
{
    Node* t = NULL;
    t = Input(t, n);

    if (t->book.year_izd < p->book.year_izd)
    {
        p->left = t;
        p->chaild = p->left;
    }
    else
    {
        p->right = t;
        p->chaild = p->right;
    }

    return p;
}

void print_tree(Node* p, int level)
{
    if (p)
    {
        std::cout << endl << endl;
        print_tree(p->left, level + 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < level; i++)
            wcout << L"    ";

        wcout << p->book.year_izd << endl;
        print_tree(p->right, level + 1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    system("color 0A");
    //setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    wcin.imbue(locale("rus_rus.866"));
    wcout.imbue(locale("rus_rus.866"));
    Node* tree = NULL;
    Node* t;
    t = Input(tree, 0);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        Second_Insert(search_and_second_insert(t), i);

    print_tree(t, 0);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Как оказалось причина была проста: я плохо разобрался с указателями и с самим алгоритмом. Ответ есть в книге Павловской под названием: C_C++. Программирование на языке высокого уровня. В моем случае требовалось написать код для текущей информации о книгах в библиотеке. Вот само решение.*

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include <locale>

using std::wcin;
using std::wcout;
using std::endl;
using std::locale;

struct Books
{
  wchar_t number_UDK[10];
  wchar_t FIO_autors[20];
  wchar_t name_of_the_book[20];
  wint_t year_izd;
  wchar_t Kolvo[50];
};

struct Node
{
  Books book;
  Node *left, *right;
};
```

Далее идет функция, задача которой ввести значение корня, выделив для него память указателю на структуру Node.

```
Node *Input_first(Node *root)
{
    root = new Node;
    wcout << L"Введите данные книги." << endl;
    wcout << L"ФИО Автора: "; wcin >> root->book.FIO_autors; wcout << endl;
    wcout << L"Номер УДК: "; wcin >> root->book.number_UDK; wcout << endl;
    wcout << L"Название книги: "; wcin >> root->book.name_of_the_book; wcout    << endl;
    wcout << L"Количество экземпляров: "; wcin >> root->book.Kolvo; wcout << endl;
    wcout << L"Год издания: "; wcin >> root->book.year_izd;wcin.get(); wcout << endl; 
    root->left = root->right = NULL;
    return root;
}
```

Далее с помощью функции "search_and_second_insert" производится заполнение других узлов дерева. Для чего производится поиск нужного узла (если добавляемое значение меньше корневого узла, то влево, если больше - вправо, пока указатель parent в цикле while не стал нулевым) и  последующие проверки условий для дальнейшего добавления узла в право или влево благодаря указателю t1, который хранит адрес узла parent, пройденного циклом, только на один шаг назад.

```
Node *search_and_second_insert(Node *tree)
{
   Node *parent = tree, *t1;
   Node *pnew = new Node;

   wcout << L"ФИО Автора: "; wcin >> pnew->book.FIO_autors; wcout << endl;
   wcout << L"Номер УДК: "; wcin >> pnew->book.number_UDK; wcout << endl;
   wcout << L"Название книги: "; wcin >> pnew->book.name_of_the_book; wcout << endl;
   wcout << L"Количество экземпляров: "; wcin >> pnew->book.Kolvo; wcout << endl;
   wcout << L"Год издания: "; wcin >> pnew->book.year_izd; wcin.get(); wcout << endl;
   pnew->left = pnew->right = NULL;

   bool found = false;
   while (parent && !found)
   {    

      t1 = parent;
      if ((pnew->book.year_izd == parent->book.year_izd))
      {
        found = true;
      }
      else if (pnew->book.year_izd < parent->book.year_izd)
      {
        parent = parent->left;
      }

      else
      {
        parent = parent->right;
      }

   }
if (found)
    return parent;

if (pnew->book.year_izd < t1->book.year_izd)
    t1->left = pnew;
else
    t1->right = pnew;
return pnew;
}
```

Далее рекурсивный просмотр дерева и сама функция main

```
void print_tree(Node *p, int level)
{
  Node *print = p;
  if (print)
  {
      std::cout<<endl<<endl;
      print_tree(print->left, level + 1);
       for (int i = 0; i < level; i++)
            wcout << L"    ";
      wcout << print->book.year_izd << endl;
      print_tree(print->right, level + 1);
  }
}

int main()
{
   system("color 0A");
   //setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
   wcin.imbue(locale("rus_rus.866"));
   wcout.imbue(locale("rus_rus.866"));
   Node *root = NULL;
   Node *tree;
   tree = Input_first(root);
   for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
     search_and_second_insert(tree);

    print_tree(tree, 0);

   _getch();
  return 0;
 }
```

Дальше надо будет реализовать алгоритм удаления из дерева.